# Flutter, Detecting that other apps are launched

Tags: flutter, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to develop an app that prevents a user from starting other application when my app is running. The scenario:

1. my app starts the timer
2. app detects launch of another app (could be anything other than my app)
3. if it detects, it cancels some achievements

Can anyone help? I saw some solutions on this topic, but could not find anything in Flutter.

Any ideas would help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to do that but easy one to observe your app situation, you can use [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) to detect your app is background or not.

But if the case is not being background it is just depending to launch an app so there is a few ways which suggest in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381172/12880676) you can try them.